PDF format limitation or? Proper PDF creation impossible with image height greater than 23950 pixels (one large page)?
Is a maximum of 23950 pixels image height at some point in a PDF creation process
a general limitation of the PDF format for a single page?
MY TEST EXAMPLE

    image dimensions in px:
    width: 1402
    height: 23950
    
    image print resolution:
    370,95 mm
    6336,77 mm
    96,000 pixels/in
    96,000 pixels/in

I'm not sure if it's possible to properly show a PDF document at 100% size when the image height has to be 23951 pixels or higher. It's an impossible task for me somehow.
But why?

That isn't a PDF limitation, it may be a limitation of the Creator. PDF pages have a MediaBox which is a rectangle comprising 4 numbers. Typical implementation limits for numbers are +/-2^32 for integers and +/-3.403^38 for reals. However Acrobat itself is not capable of drawing a page with dimenstions anything like that. At various times Acrobat has had a co-ordinate limit of +/-16384, +/-32768 and probably some other ones too. I'm not sure where K J is quoting that GS limit from, it's not a limit I recognise. Depending on the resolution I've seen GS print documents up to 2 miles on a side.

From emulating your dimensions you have an image that is
/Width 1402 pixel units
/Height 23950 pixel units
6 0 obj
<</BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/.../Width 1402/Height 23950/Length ..../Subtype/Image>>stream

You intend to use proposed Area of 370.95 mm x 6336.77 mm in a default units PDF, where each PDF unit is considered as if is 1/72" and has a Default PDF limitation of 200" (508 cm) maximum. So the MediaBox must be 14400 or less
4 0 obj
<</Contents 7 0 R /MediaBox[ 0 0 1051 17962]/...

This will be a breach of Acrobat Readers abilities and it will as many PDF viewers could, simply refuse to render more than 200"
ERROR with attempting to exceed 507.941 cm viewer defaults limitation

However you wish to view at actual size with a NOMINAL dimension  of 633.603 cm high which is not a problem if the PDF is edited for desired /UserUnits

So you will need to place the image at half height and double the desired unit like this so that the Maximum is less than 14400.
4 0 obj
<</Contents 7 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 525.75 8981.25]/UserUnit 2/Parent 2 0 R

